# Rust: error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned

Tags: rust

I tried to install [nyx-net](https://github.com/RUB-SysSec/nyx-net), but during the installation process an error occurs, which I can't fix because I don't know the Rust good.

Terminal output:

```
nyx-net git:(main) ./setup.sh
[?] Checking submodules ...
[?] Checking QEMU-NYX ...
[?] Checking NYX-Net fuzzer ...
[*] Compiling NYX-Net fuzzer ...
[?] Checking submodules ...
[?] Checking rust_fuzzer ...
   Compiling fuzz_runner v0.1.0 (/home/ilorj/Desktop/protocols/nyx-net/fuzzer/libnyx/fuzz_runner)
error[E0793]: reference to packed field is unaligned
   --> /home/ilorj/Desktop/protocols/nyx-net/fuzzer/libnyx/fuzz_runner/src/lib.rs:221:9
    |
221 |         &self.feedback_data.shared.ijon.max_data
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = note: fields of packed structs are not properly aligned, and creating a misaligned reference is undefined behavior (even if that reference is never dereferenced)
    = help: copy the field contents to a local variable, or replace the reference with a raw pointer and use `read_unaligned`/`write_unaligned` (loads and stores via `*p` must be properly aligned even when using raw pointers)

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0793`.
error: could not compile `fuzz_runner` due to previous error
```

lib.rs file:

```
impl FuzzRunner for QemuProcess {
    fn run_test(&mut self) -> Result<TestInfo, Box<dyn Error>> {
        self.send_payload();
        let ops_used = self.feedback_data.shared.interpreter.executed_opcode_num;
        if self.aux.result.crash_found != 0 {
            return Ok(TestInfo {ops_used, exitreason: ExitReason::Crash(self.aux.misc.as_slice().to_vec())});
        }
        if self.aux.result.payload_write_attempt_found != 0{
            return Ok(TestInfo {ops_used, exitreason: ExitReason::InvalidWriteToPayload(self.aux.misc.as_slice().to_vec())});
        }
        if self.aux.result.timeout_found != 0 {
            return Ok(TestInfo {ops_used, exitreason: ExitReason::Timeout});
        }
        if self.aux.result.asan_found != 0 {
            return Ok(TestInfo {ops_used, exitreason: ExitReason::Asan});
        }
        if self.aux.result.success != 0{
            return Ok(TestInfo {ops_used, exitreason: ExitReason::Normal(0)});
        }
        println!("unknown exeuction result!!");
        return Ok(TestInfo {ops_used, exitreason: ExitReason::FuzzerError});
    }

    fn run_create_snapshot(&mut self) -> bool{
        assert_eq!(self.aux.result.tmp_snapshot_created,0);
        self.send_payload();
        return self.aux.result.tmp_snapshot_created == 1;
    }

    fn delete_snapshot(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>{
        if self.aux.result.tmp_snapshot_created != 0 {
            self.aux.config.changed = 1;
            self.aux.config.discard_tmp_snapshot = 1;
            self.send_payload();
            if self.aux.result.tmp_snapshot_created != 0 {
                println!("AUX BUFFER {:#?}",self.aux);
            }
            assert_eq!( self.aux.result.tmp_snapshot_created, 0);
        }
        return Ok(());
    }


    fn run_redqueen(&mut self) -> Result<RedqueenInfo, Box<dyn Error>> {
        self.aux.config.changed = 1;
        self.aux.config.redqueen_mode=1;
        self.send_payload();
        self.aux.config.changed = 1;
        self.aux.config.redqueen_mode=0;
        let rq_file = format!("{}/redqueen_workdir_{}/redqueen_results.txt",self.params.workdir,self.params.qemu_id);
        return Ok(self.parse_redqueen_file(&rq_file));
    }

    fn run_cfg(&mut self) -> Result<CFGInfo, Box<dyn Error>> {
        //println!("TRACE!!!!");
        self.aux.config.trace_mode=1;
        self.aux.config.changed = 1;
        self.send_payload();
        self.aux.config.changed = 1;
        self.aux.config.trace_mode=0;
        return Ok(CFGInfo {});
    }

    fn shutdown(&mut self) -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
        self.shutdown();
        return Ok(());
    }
    fn input_buffer(&mut self) -> &mut [u8] {
        &mut self.payload[..]
    }
    fn bitmap_buffer(&self) -> &[u8] {
        self.bitmap
    }
    fn ijon_max_buffer(&self) -> &[u64] {
        &self.feedback_data.shared.ijon.max_data  **/* <---- error is here */**
    }
    fn set_input_size(&mut self, _size: usize) {
        //self.payload[4..].copy_from_slice(&(size as u32).to_le_bytes());
    }
}
```

Can someone help with this error?

cargo 1.69.0 (6e9a83356 2023-04-12)

rustc 1.69.0 (84c898d65 2023-04-16)

Ubuntu 20.04

I searched google for something that might help, but found nothing.

Comment: This code used to be allowed, but is now prohibited. The library probably uses a Rust version lower than you have. Check if it has a more updated version, or downgrade Rust.